# Maior número em matriz, não exibe

Tags: c, matriz

Esse código não mostra como deveria o maior elemento inserido na matriz nem a posição correta.
Qual é o erro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define lin 4
#define col 4
int main()
{
   int mat[lin][col], i, j, maior=mat[0][0], pos_i, pos_j;

   printf("Informe os elementos da matriz\n");
   for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
      for(j=0;j<col;j++){
         printf("[%d][%d] = ", i,j);
         scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
         if(mat[i][j] > maior) {
            maior=mat[i][j];
            pos_i=i;
            pos_j=j;
         }
        }
   }
   printf("O maior elemento da matriz: %d\n", maior);
   printf("Posicao: [%d][%d]\n", pos_i,pos_j);
   return 0;
}
```

Assim ele exibe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Para menor valor matriz ele exibe corretamente, mas para maior não.

Comment: Poderia ser um pouco mais especifico? talvez um exemplo prático do que seria o erro

Comment: Isso tá com cheiro de lixo de memória por causa do `maior=mat[0][0]`... Tenta iniciar o `maior` com zero.

Comment: Parece que faltou inicializar mesmo o maior.

Comment: Deu certo. E pq em menor não é necessário?

Comment: @DH além de estar correto o que você disse, não faria o mínimo sentido pegar o "maior" de uma matriz que ainda não recebeu dados.

Comment: @user41836 pode ser necessário sim, mas talvez você não tenha testado com números bem altos. Experimente o menor com todos os números muito grandes.

Comment: Até quantas casas decimais um int aguenta?

Comment: @user41836 int nao tem casa decimal, por isso se chama "inteiro".

Comment: @DH não quer postar uma resposta? Acho que seria justo a escolhida ser sua, pois você identificou primeiro o erro.

Comment: Quer dizer quantos dígitos, quando digito um valor muito alto, ele mostra outro valor.

Comment: @user não é "digitos", mas sim o valor mais alto. Geralmente é 2147483647, e isso menos um no negativo. Se for unsigned int, aí o que seria negativo vc passa a ter a mais no positivo.

Comment: Poisé, agora percebi, havia esquecido disso.

Comment: @Bacco nah, sem stress com a reputação, o que importa é ajudar :) Além do mais, eu só olhei isso enquanto dava build no sistema da empresa, nem devia estar mais olhando aqui aushauhsuahsua

Comment: @DH de qq forma já escolheram uma. Fica pra outra ocasião :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
   int mat[lin][col], i, j, maior=mat[0][0], pos_i, pos_j;
   //                             ^^^^^^^^^ LIXO
```

Quando fazes a atribuicao a `maior` o conteudo de `mat[0][0]` é lixo.
Tens que fazer essa atribuicao **depois** de atribuir valores ao array.

Answer (score 0):

Você não inicializou a sua matriz **e** inicializou maior com o valor de mat[0][0], que você não sabe qual é.

Tenta assim:

```
   int mat[lin][col];
   int i, j, pos_i, pos_j;

   /* inicializa a matriz */
   for(i = 0; i < lin; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
          mat[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   int maior;

   printf("Informe os elementos da matriz\n");
   for(i = 0; i < lin; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
         printf("[%d][%d] = ", i,j);
         scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);

         /* atualiza maior se for a primeira interacao, */
         /* ou se o valor corrente for maior            */
         if( (i == 0 && j == 0) || (mat[i][j] > maior) ) {
            maior=mat[i][j];
            pos_i=i;
            pos_j=j;
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você sempre deveria inicializar as variáveis e inicializar uma variável com outra que não foi inicializada não resolve, como feito na linha:

```
maior=mat[0][0]
```

As variáveis em C e C++ virão com os valores que estavam previamente na memória para ganhar uma pequena vantagem... isso significa que não é garantido que elas comecem com 0.

Foi feito assim porque na época era uma vantagem de performance significativa (se você fosse atribuir um valor a variável mais tarde e utilizar ela). Hoje em dia não é mais lá grande coisa e deveria sempre inicializar, mas esse trabalho hoje é feito pelos programadores dessa linguagem.